# Full app - Associated Domain for app clip invocation

Tags: ios, code-signing-entitlements, apple-appclips, apple-app-site-associate

According to Apple documentation, when a user installs the full app, the app clip invocation launches the full app. And it says to associate the full app with the website.

Does this association mean to add `appclips:<domain>` or `applinks:<domain>` in the full app's entitlement?

I know `applinks:<domain>` should be added to the app clip. What I am not sure is the full app's entitlement for associated domain.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/configuring_your_app_clip_s_launch_experience

> Important When users install an App Clip’s corresponding app, the full
> app replaces the App Clip. Every invocation from that moment on
> launches the full app instead of the App Clip. As a result, you must
> also associate the full app with your website. Additionally, the full
> app must handle all invocations and offer the App Clip’s
> functionality.

Comment: It's `appclips:<domain>` that works for me.

Comment: I've written down everything that I did here: https://github.com/aheze/AppClipQuickStart

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the association means you need to add `applinks:<domain>` to your full app and `appclips:<domain>` to your app clip.

EDIT: as @Senseful mentioned in the comment below, adding `applinks:<domain>` to the App Clip is also necessary

Comment: I found that adding `applinks:` to the App Clip was also necessary as was detailed here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658974?answerId=632569022#632569022